# Is it possible to purchase a domain name from Google to take advantage of their two factor authentication?

Tags: google, godaddy, authentication

We are planning to purchase a domain name from Google. Somewhere I have seen GoDaddy.com and eNom.com are the Google's partner. So can I purchase domain from Google?

The reason for purchasing from Google instead of purchasing directly from eNom or GoDaddy is we require a two way authentication for our account. eNom does not have 2 factor authentication (they use  account validation which is optional extra login security for your account)  and GoDaddy has only in US.

Google already have two step verification for Gmail and Google services. I am hopeful that if I purchase from Google, I may get the benefit of using the 2 factor authentication to login a eNom or GoDaddy account to control domain and DNS.

If I purchase domain from Google can we login to the eNom or GoDaddy account directly (which should not happen because I want two factor authentication) or should we login to the Google by using  2 factor authentication account and then only we can access domain account?

Comment: Google does not sell domain names.

Comment: I found this https://domains.google.com/about/ and some other links where they stated eNom and GoDaddy are Google's partner

Comment: I'm sure they are. But that doesn't make Google a seller of domains just like it doesn't make enom or godaddy a search engine.

Comment: @JohnConde They actually do since recently. Though I believe they're not a registrar themselves actually.

Comment: Looks like [they are just getting started](https://domains.google.com/about/). It should be clear that this is independant of godaddy and enom.

Comment: This sounds rather strange to me. Google absolutely rates registrars according to quality and eNom is the worst I know of and GoDaddy the best. In fact, eNom is so bad, that it comprises 4% of all the entries in my database (hackers, bad bots, scrapers, etc) where the next on the list is less than 1%. eNom is a bad neighborhood. Why would Google partner with one of the registrars/hosts with the lowest quality site on the net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is in the process of launching domain registration.   Right now their domain registration service is an invite only service:

[image]

You can [give them your email address](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1goX7E-gKq1C9WN-vX2fL_O3lXgBCFVmdVgAAJHwv2eo/viewform) and they will give you access at some point.   That is how it worked with Gmail and other products they rolled out.

I don't have access to this Google service myself, so I can't check whether or not you can manage your domain solely with your Google account that uses two factor authentication.   I'd imagine they would want that to be possible.

---

Another possibility for a domain registrar with 2-factor authentication would be [Amazon's Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/).   They have [instructions for enabling multi-factor authentication on your Amazon AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/details/mfa/).